# how can I tell if a function can be used in a context manager?

Tags: python, torch

To change the printing precision of numpy array `x`, I've been using this:

```
with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
    print(x)
```

I want to do the same for torch tensor `aTensor`, but the below doesn't work (I get `AttributeError: __enter__` ):

```
with torch.set_printoptions(precision=2):
    print(aTensor)
```

I'm new to python and looked around and read that for a function to be used in a context manager, it needs to have `__enter__` and `__exit__`. But when I tried to check, I get that neither `np.printoptions` nor `torch.set_printoptions` has `__enter__` as an attribute: `hasattr(np.printoptions, "__enter__")` returns `False` and the same for `hasattr(torch.set_printoptions, "__enter__")`.

But the former can be used in the context manager but the latter not. Why is this?

The direct problem of torch tensors print precision I can deal with by changing precision, printing and then changing precision back. I'm more interested in learning about the basics of the context manager. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `np.printoptions` doesn't have an `__enter__` attribute is that it's a function that *returns* a context manager; it's not a context manager itself.

```py
>>> from contextlib import AbstractContextManager
>>> cm = np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)
>>> cm
<contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at 0x636f6e747874>
>>> isinstance(cm, AbstractContextManager)
True
```

Note that not all context managers are going to be `contextlib._GeneratorContextManager` objects; `numpy` just happens to be using `contextlib` from the standard library to create this context manager.

**To answer your literal question**, that last line of code will check if something is a context manager; you can check if it's an instance of `contextlib.AbstractContextManager`. That's how you should do it if you need to check if something is a context manager in your code. If you just need to check adhoc for your own knowledge and can't be bothered to do it that way, then you can: check in the REPL that it has `__enter__` and `__exit__` attributes, either by trying to auto-complete them or by using `dir()`; try to use it as a context manager; or check the documentation/implementation.

---

Unlike `np.printoptions`, `torch.set_printoptions` doesn't even return a context manager, which is why you got that `AttributeError`. However, you can create your own context manager to handle `torch.set_printoptions` for you, which you could then use in the same way as `np.printoptions`. Here's an example; I haven't tested this, but any potential issues can be resolved. You can see relevant code [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/_tensor_str.html).

```py
import contextlib
import copy

import torch

@contextlib.contextmanager
def torch_set_printoptions_cm(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # be warned, torch._tensor_str is a private module,
        # not bound by API guarantees
        original_options = torch._tensor_str.PRINT_OPTS
        torch._tensor_str.PRINT_OPTS = copy.copy(original_options)

        torch.set_printoptions(*args, **kwargs)
        yield torch._tensor_str.PRINT_OPTS
    finally:
        torch._tensor_str.PRINT_OPTS = original_options
```

You could then do what you tried:

```py
with torch_set_printoptions_cm(precision=2):
    print(aTensor)
```

Comment: Thank you! This of course worked. I'll need to study context managers and decorators. 

What does "torch._tensor_str is a private module, not bound by API guarantees" mean? I followed the link to the source code for torch._tensor_str but I'm not getting the comment.

Comment: @puddles `_tensor_str` starts with an underscore, which is a Python convention to indicate that it's a private thing – a private module in this case. Usually it means that

Comment: (whoops, took too long continuing/editing after accidentally sending) ... Usually it means that the developers reserve the right to refactor it without regard for any policy they might have about API support or stability, since it's explicitly private by convention. That said, my guess is that this particular private API is pretty unlikely to change very often; and if it does, I would expect it to be at least as easy as it is now to do what that context manager I wrote is doing.

Comment: Best case would be if they change it to have context manager support built-in. You might consider opening an issue with PyTorch. If you do, I'd appreciate if you mentioned it here so I could follow it. :)

Comment: That's good to know, that underscore-before-private convention. I opened an issue with Pytorch [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51002)